# How to develop an infinite scroll in both sides? +JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, infinite-scroll

In order to save memory when loading the page that is displaying the values of thousands of rows DB I've develop the following code:

```
const dataContainer = document.getElementById("driversContainer")
let isLoading = false

function appendData(data){
  const html = Object.values(data).map(({id, name, surname, visitedCountries}) => (addDriver(id, name, surname, visitedCountries))).join('');
  dataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if(isLoading) return;

    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;
    if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) {
        isLoading = true;
        loadMore();
      }
})

async function loadMore() {
  try {
    const offset = dataContainer.children.length;
    const response = await fetch(`${url}?offset=${offset}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    document.querySelector('.spinner').style.visibility = 'visible';

    setTimeout(() => {
      appendData(data);
      isLoading = false;
      document.querySelector('.spinner').style.visibility = 'collapse';
    }, 1000);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

It works properly when scrolling down I am unable to find a proper way to do it in the other way round. Tried several methods but they didn`t get the expected result.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

I tried the following code and the result was not what I expected:

```
const dataContainer = document.getElementById("driversContainer");
const maxItemCount = 9;
const data = [];
let isLoading = false;

async function loadData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const dataJson = await response.json();
    data.push(...dataJson);
    appendData(data.slice(0, maxItemCount));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function appendData(data) {
  const existingItemCount = dataContainer.children.length;
  const html = data.map(({ id, name, surname, visitedCountries }) =>
    addDriver(id, name, surname, visitedCountries)
  ).join('');
  dataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

  const excessItemCount = existingItemCount + data.length - maxItemCount;
  if (excessItemCount > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < excessItemCount; i++) {
      dataContainer.removeChild(dataContainer.firstChild);
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (isLoading) return;

  const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;
  if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) {
    isLoading = true;
    loadMore();
  }
});

async function loadMore() {
  try {
    const offset = dataContainer.children.length;
    const response = await fetch(`${url}?offset=${offset}`);
    const newData = await response.json();
    data.push(...newData);
    document.querySelector('.spinner').style.visibility = 'visible';

    setTimeout(() => {
      appendData(newData);
      isLoading = false;
      document.querySelector('.spinner').style.visibility = 'collapse';
    }, 1000);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function addItemsToTop() {
  const existingItemCount = dataContainer.children.length;
  if (existingItemCount >= maxItemCount) {
    const newData = data.slice(existingItemCount - maxItemCount, existingItemCount);
    const html = newData.map(({ id, name, surname, visitedCountries }) =>
      addDriver(id, name, surname, visitedCountries)
    ).join('');
    dataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);

    const excessItemCount = existingItemCount + newData.length - maxItemCount;
    if (excessItemCount > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < excessItemCount; i++) {
        dataContainer.removeChild(dataContainer.lastChild);
      }
    }
  }
}

loadData();
```